# How to make source code a part of XML documentation and not violate DRY?

Tags: c#, .net, dry, documentation-generation

I'd like to add parts of the source code to the XML documentation. I could copy & paste source code to some <code> elements, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Says hello world in a very basic way:
/// <code>
///   System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
///   System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
///   System.Console.ReadKey();
/// </code>
/// </summary>
static void Main() 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Maintaining this will be painful. Are there other possibilities to add source code to the XML documentation in C#?

I am processing the XML documentation with Sandcastle and would like to make a technical help file (*.chm) out of it. I would like to add parts or complete method bodies to the that help file.

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the comment from slide_rule. I have added a more realistic and less trivial example:

Suppose I have some method like this:

```
public decimal CalculateFee(Bill bill)
{
    if (bill.TotalSum < 5000) return 500;
    else
    {
        if (bill.ContainsSpecialOffer) return bill.TotalSum * 0.01;
        else return bill.TotalSum * 0.02;
    }
}
```

It would be nice to have a possibility to add the information how the fee is calculated into the technical help file.

The most obvious solution would be write down the algorithm as prosaic text into the comment like: "If the bill has a total sum less than 5000 then ...".

Another solution would be to copy & paste the body of the method into the comment field and put it into a <code> element. This method body can be understood quite easily, even without much knowledge about C# -- so there is nothing wrong to put it into a technical help file.

**Both solutions violate the DRY principle!** I would like to add method bodies or pieces of a method body into the help file, without duplicating information.

Is this possible in C#? (I think RDoc for Ruby is capable of doing this, but I need some solution in C#)

Comment: It seems to me that you're fighting the purpose of the XML documentation - if I understand it correctly, the XML doc is more about API documentation than application or technical documentation. Could you provide a less trivial example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for that hint ... may that's the reason no one answers. ;-)

Comment: I would "document" technical help file using unit test cases. Since developers will be the one whose reading it, unit test will provide the best, most certain way of defining things in the code.

Comment: @ Adrian Godong:
Something like this quite often happens to me: Problem domain guy: "Hey, how do we calculate the fees right now? I don't have the requirements document by hand. Can you have a look into the source code?" Me: "Err ... sure" *Opens help file and shows him the help file* Me: "If you want you can check out the help file from the SVN and you are up-to-date. This help file is less scary than source code. Give it a try."

Comment: @RunningMonkey - I fear the subtext of that conversation is: PDG: "Hey, how do we calculate the fees right now? I feel that your time is worth less than mine, I've forgotten where the docs are, and can't be bothered to look for them. Can you dig them out for me?" - Showing them where to look in the help file (or even source code) isn't likely to solve that one :( Alternatively, PDG thinks "Oh, the dev's working on the app right now, they're bound to have the code I need to hand, I'll go ask them"

Comment: @Zhaph - It's often a question how you deliver information. A help file is less scary than source code. I have PDG around me who read small bits of source code, if I it's properly written. They even read log files, if I explain to them. The idea of the help file would serve as a vehicle to transport a good mix of problem domain and solution domain information.

Comment: @Adrian Godong: Writing unit tests that provide sample code is something I do all the time. It's a good idea, but doesn't solve the question of how to get the code from the unit test into the XML comments without copy & paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing an idea out there...

Automate a process that looks for code blocks delimited in some way, then inject that code into the XML comment.

```
/// <summary>
/// Says hello world in a very basic way:
/// <code>
///     Code block 1
/// </code>
/// </summary>
static void Main() 
{
    // Code block 1 start
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
    // Code block 1 end
}
```

I know it's not pretty, but it's a start! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with a more standard approach for documenting the code by using fields like

```
<summary>
   <description>Displays Hello World!</description>
   <arguments>None</arguments>
   <returns>None</returns>
</summary>
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Although you definitely should do that as well, often an example is really helpful when you are reading documentation. XML Comments has a feature for that since it has an 'example' element, but the question is how to put code into that 'example' element while ensuring that this code stays current and correct, and without violating the DRY principle.

Comment: I know exactly what the question was/is.  Don't assume that because I didn't provide exactly what he wanted that I didn't read the question.

Answer (score 1):

To me the main purpose of the comments is to describe the code. copy and pasting the code will not fullfill that purpose, so I guess my question ould be "What's the intended purpose of the documentation?" Do you wish to document what the method does to some one calling the method+ (kinda like API documentation) or do you what to document how the method works so that another developer can maintain the source code? or something different?

If it's the first I would use the code at all. I would state that the method calculates the fee taking into account the different rules for discounts and whatelse is included in the algorithm. The business rules for those calculation is in an API context not an important information, they might very well change with out the API changing (only the implementation behind the interface would change)

If it's the second purpose repeating the code will still not fullfill the purpose. Repeating something does make it any clearer, repeating something does make it any clearer, but an example of how to use the method might help explain. A usage example will not be a repetition and will only need to be changed if the method signature changes and then a changes in the documentation would be required anyways

Answer (score 0):

You may want to play around with the [include element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx). I've never used it, so I don't know whether you can mix that element with the other, regular XML Comment elements, but the the way I read the (sparse) documentation, it doesn't look like it.

While that would be the best option, even if that's not possible, you might be able to combine usage of that element with a script that finds the relevant pieces of code and inserts it into the XML file.

I'd probably take another route, though. Since the output of XML Comments is just an XML file, you can process it after it has been created, but before running Sandcastle on it. I would then make another script that looks for all the code that needs to go into the help file, and extract that to a separate XML file.

These two XML files can then be merged using XSLT and passed on to SandCastle.

How would you identify code that needs to go into the help file? Off the top of my head, I can think of three options:

- Attributes
- Regions
- Comments

Personally, I'd prefer Attributes.

On a closing note I'd like to point out that while this is certainly possible, it's probably more work than just copying and pasting and keeping a bit of discipline :)